# npm install -g webpack gives tar.unpack untar error

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I created a new user on my Mac and tried this. This normally works in my other account. This new user is an administrator also.

```
  npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/test/.npm/webpack/1.11.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! Darwin 14.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "webpack"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:35:25',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:47:53',
npm ERR!      'FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/test/WebstormProjects/babel-test/npm-debug.log
```

I am not very good with the UNIX stuff and things, I just wish these things would be more easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start using `nvm` and it will save you from using `sudo` at all.

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: cool, you might have saved me from the node install nonsense, it nvm best practice now?

Comment: so I installed nvm and then ran `nvm install 0.12.7` which worked. however I still get the same error when trying the **npm install -g**, opened a new termainal and ran `node -v`  and get 0.12.4

Answer (score 3):

From the looks of it, since it says EACCES, it is probably getting an access denied from the system. If you are installing globally on unix you must use sudo.

```
$ sudo npm install -g webpack
```

Comment: thanks but I would prefer not to do that because my experience with doing this is things end up going funny. Hopefully I can get it to work like my other account where I don't need Sudo

Comment: Also I ran  npm install -g webpack on my other account, why would I also need to run it in this account, so many problems with node and account permissions, wish they would get it down nice and simple like windows.